# Как использовать отношение моделей в самой модели?

Tags: laravel

Допустим есть модель Order, в ней есть метод:

```
public function partners()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Order','partner_id','id');
}
```

Пытаюсь использовать это отношение в самой модели Order:

```
public function getPartnerName($partner_id)
{
    return $this->partners()->where('partner_id', $partner_id)->first();
}
```

Но getPartnerName ничего не возвращает.

Метод getPartnerName вызываю в шаблоне так:

```
$order->getPartnerName($order->partner_id);
```

В итоге пусто.

Как получить значения в шаблоне используя заданное отношение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В модели Order:

```
public function partner() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Partner::class);
}

public function getPartnerNameAttribute()
{
    return $this->partner->name;
}
```

В модели Partner если хочешь получать заказы партнера:

```
public function orders() {
    return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
}
```

Потом в blade: `{{ $order->partnerName}}` или `{{ $order->partner_name}}`

Пробуй так, не сработает, то попробуй подовлять ", 'partner_id', 'id'"
Если преобразуешь в массив и хочешь чтобы было там partner_name то в модель Order:

```
 protected $appends = ['partner_name'];
```

Comment: спасибо огромное! помогла замена на belongsTo

Comment: Ой, я в последнем коде скопировал у себя, забыл переделать под тебя, исправил, это если вдруг в массив нужно преобразовать. Очень рад что работает. В начале смотря на твой код я думал что партнеры это сами заказы, кароче не важно. Вот почитай чтобы не путаться: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 1):

Я так понял что Order может иметь много Order по partner_id.
Зачем ты используешь в getPartnerName параметр $partner_id  если всеравно передаешь туда id текущей модели $order->id через этот код `$order->getPartnerName($order->id)`?

Не понятно где ты используешь $order->getPartnerName($order->id), я бы больше понял что тебе надо если объяснил бы.

Может вместо $order->id у тебя должно быть что-то типа $orderPartner->id?

И метод getPartnerName изменить на такой:

```
public function getPartnerName($partner_id)
{
    return $this->partners()->where('id', $partner_id)->first();
}
```

Только еще не понятно почему метод называется getPartnerName а возвращать нужно модель, а не имя

Comment: $order->getPartnerName($order->id)  это во view. Я в вопросе в ручную набрал ошибся. В коде было $order->getPartnerName($order->partner_id) 
(В вопросе тоже поправлю.)

Comment: а нет, смотри, ты получаешь в $this->hasMany('App\Order','partner_id','id'); партнеров по partner_id у которых это поле равно id текущего order, а в ->where('partner_id', $partner_id) ты получаешь партнеров текущего order у которых partner_id равен текущего order partner_id, а таких походу нет.

Comment: но в базе каждому order соответствует один partner.

Comment: я это понял, у заказа есть свой партнер который можно получить по belongsTo и еще есть заказы которые принадлежат этому, которых ты получаешь через hasMany. Я так понял что ты хочешь что-то сделать, но `->where('id', $partner_id)` тут не подходит

Comment: тебе надо получить партнера заказа, который только один может быть?

Comment: партнер у заказа может быть один, а партнер может принадлежать к не ограниченному  количеству заказов

Comment: Парнер это тоже 'App\Order'?  Что должен делать метод getPartnerName опиши получше

Comment: В таблице orders есть поле partner_id, которое связано с таблицей partners.
Метод getPartnerName должен возвращать name партнера из таблицы partners, в соответствии с partner_id

Comment: добавил новый ответ, пометь его как правильный ответ если работает

Comment: спасибо огромное! помогла замена на belongsTo